# How to fetch user role from DB using LDAP login using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap

Hi I am novice to Spring Boot and LDAP. I am facing problems!

I could login via LDAP but I cant fetch user role which is stored in my Database. I do get the following error:

```
org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl cannot be cast to com.test.rnd.geo.web.dto.CustomUser
```

I had tried this:

```
    private CustomUser getUserDetails() {
        CustomUser userDetails = (CustomUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        LOGGER.info("Deatils:  "+userDetails);
        LOGGER.info("UserName: " + userDetails.getUsername());
        LOGGER.info("Auth Token: " + userDetails.getAuthToken());
        LOGGER.info("User Role size: " + userDetails.getAuthorities().size());
        LOGGER.info("User Role : " + userDetails.getAuthorities());


        return userDetails;
    }
```

I am getting error to fetch this getUserDetails() function.

```
        CustomUser customUser = getUserDetails();
```

Here is my CustomUser Class:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class CustomUser implements UserDetails {


    private String username;
    private String password;
    private List<RoleEntity> authorities;
    private String authToken;

    public String getAuthToken() {
        return authToken;
    }

    public void setAuthToken(String authToken) {
        this.authToken = authToken;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(List<RoleEntity> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }



    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomUser{" +
                "username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='****" + '\'' +
                ", authorities=" + authorities +
                ", AuthToken='" + authToken + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Here's my WebSecurityConfig:

```
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
                .authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider)
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchFilter("(&(mail={0})(memberOf=CN=aa,OU=Security Group,OU=aa,DC=aa,DC=com))")
                .contextSource()
                .url("ldap://www.domain.com:3268/dc=v,dc=com")
                .managerDn("aaa")
                .managerPassword("aaa");

    }
```

Repository Class:

```
@Repository
public class UserAuthRepository {
    @Autowired
    private InterServiceConnector serviceConnector;
    @Autowired
    private httpsServiceConnector httpsServiceConnector;
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG
            = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationProvider.class);


    @Value("${dmzAddress}")
    private String host;

    public CustomUser authenticateUser(String userName, String password) {
        CustomUser customUser = null;
        try {
            customUser = null;

            LOG.info("UserAuthRepository::authenticateUser:: userName" + userName);
//            LOG.info("UserAuthRepository::authenticateUser:: password ********");

            Request request = new Request();
            request.setUsername(userName);
            request.setPassword(password);

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            String jsonInput = gson.toJson(request);

//            LOG.info("UserAuthRepository::authenticateUser:: Authentication Token :: " + request.getAuthToken());

            String user = null;
            if (host.contains("http://")){
                user = serviceConnector.serviceCall(jsonInput, "portalLogin", "post", request.getAuthToken());
            }
            else{
                user = httpsServiceConnector.serviceCall(jsonInput, "portalLogin", "post");
            }
//            String user = serviceConnector.serviceCall(jsonInput, "portalLogin", "post", request.getAuthToken());
//          String user = httpsServiceConnector.serviceCall(jsonInput, "portalLogin", "post");
//            LOG.info("UserAuthRepository::authenticateUser:: user---->>>  " +  user);
            customUser = gson.fromJson(user, CustomUser.class);
            LOG.info("UserAuthRepository:: Custom User::  {}", customUser);
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            LOG.error("UserAuthRepository :: authenticateUser :: Parse Exception", e);
        }
        return customUser;
    }



}
```

Comment: your CustomUser class should implement the LdapUserDetails interface but it seems to me you're not doing that? Also, an instance of CustomUser shouldn't be obtained from a SecurityContextHolder but rather by calling LdapUserDetailsMapper.mapUserFromContext

Comment: @dsp_user I do get getUserName(),getAuthToken(),getAuthorities() while I do use my username and password from my DB.

Comment: both the username and password that you login with should match those stored in the ldap / ad  server (and not the credentials stored in the database). Post the entire login code and I'll have a look.

Comment: @dsp_user I have edited my Post. Please see the updated one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dsp_user gave great solutions.

Now Based on your above codes I assume that your are using a function in your Repository Class that takes username and password as the params.

Do make similar another function that takes only username as param. Call that function in your CustomLdapUserDetailsMapper Class.

Try this code:

```
@Component
public class CustomLdapUserDetailsMapper extends LdapUserDetailsMapper {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @Override
    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

        CustomUser user = userRepository.authenticationMethod(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User is not found!");
        }

        return user;
    }

}
```

I hope this would solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, @Shihab Abrar, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

First, your CustomUser should implement `LdapUserDetails` and not `UserDetails`

You also need to subclass `LdapUserDetailsMapper` because Spring will call `mapUserFromContext` and this is where you can fetch whatever data you need from your database and create an instance of CustomUser.

```
@Component
public class CustomLdapUserDetailsMapper extends LdapUserDetailsMapper {

@Autowired
private IUserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private IUserRoleRepository userRoleRepository;

@Override
 public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String   username,
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

 
    User user = userRepository.findOneByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
    }
    UserDetails userDetails = super.mapUserFromContext(ctx, username, getAuthorities(user));
   //add a constructor for your CustomUser
    return new CustomUser(user.getEmail(), user.getFullName(),  (LdapUserDetails) userDetails);
}

}
private Set<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(User user) {
    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();

    //populate authorities/user roles from User (db entity) and UserRole entities

    for (UserRole userRole : userRoleRepository.findAllByUserId(user.getId())) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole.getName()));

    }

    return authorities;
}
}
```

And finally, tell your authentication provider to use this ldap mapper class (put this in your web security code)

```
@Autowired
private CustomLdapUserDetailsMapper customLdapUserDetailsMapper;     
.... 

customAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(customLdapUserDetailsMapper);
```

UPDATE: The CustomUser code might look something like this

```
public class CustomUser implements LdapUserDetails{

private  String email;

private String fullName;

private  String username;

private LdapUserDetails ldapUserDetails;

public CustomUser(String email, String fullName, LdapUserDetails  ldapUserDetails) {
    super();
    
    this.email = email;
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.ldapUserDetails = ldapUserDetails;
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return ldapUserDetails.getAuthorities();
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return ldapUserDetails.getPassword();
}


@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return ldapUserDetails.getUsername();
}
//add all the other overrides and getter/setter methods

}
```

And the repository classes might look something like

```
   public interface IUserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    public User findOneByUsername(String username);

    public User findOneById(Integer id);

    public User findOneByEmail(String email);

}


public interface IUserRoleRepository extends JpaRepository<UserRole, Integer> {

UserRole findOneByRoleName(String rolename);//role name like admin, user, mod etc

UserRole findOneById(Integer id);//role id
}
```

Comment: its not working :(.

Comment: FYI, I am using both normal login authentication & LDAP authentication. I am facing no issue while using normal authentication but LDAP is messing around.

Comment: @eboi, don't use both kinds of authentication  at the same time. Use ldap only and see if that works and then we can go from there

Comment: I have added my Repository class in the updated post. Please check.

Comment: Also is this approach correct in web security code:
  .ldapAuthentication()
  .userDetailsContextMapper(customLdapUserDetailsMapper)

Comment: @eboi, perhaps you can use that approach, I use a slightly different approach in my own code (i.e I call setUserDetailsContextMapper). Like I said , don't try to mix both authentication methods in the same code (choose only one of them and then we can go from there ). Btw, if designed correctly, you always should let Spring do the authentication for you and I see you're trying to do that manually in your code, which is not good.

Comment: Actually I do need to fetch my user roles from the Database. And I am now trying to go to LDAP approach only.

Comment: @eboi, I'm also fetching the user roles from the database (in mapUserFromContext)

Comment: I am confused in this line : customAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(customLdapUserDetailsMapper);

Comment: @eboi, that's just ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(customLdapUserDetailsMapper); But you can probably use AuthenticationManager..userDetailsContextMapper(customLdapUserDetailsMapper) instead because it should pretty much be the same

Comment: could you please share the constructor that needs to be created for CustomUser.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Could you please tell how you are getting the user role?

Comment: @eboi, I've updated my CustomLdapUserDetailsMapper.getAuthorities method. So you're basically creating an instance of UserDetails with the db roles (the roles are stored in UserRoles table, which has a many to one relationship with the User table (one user many roles)

Comment: Could you please provide the IUserRepository & IUserRoleRepository Classes.

Comment: @eboi, I have added the repositories as well. Anyway, don't get me wrong, but you really should read up on how it all works because it's rather difficult to put this all together based on a few code snippets that you found online. I think you now understand that the approach you initially took is wrong.

Comment: But , the ldap login documetation could be clearer, admittedly.